# How to link the contents to the actual page in Rmarkdown pdf output

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am creating several reports outputting in a pdf file via calling a markdown file from r. When a pdf file is created I would like to clink in the contents and go to the actual page.

The code that I am using at the moment is :

````
---
title : "My report"
author: "Myself"
output:   pdf_document: 
         fig_caption: yes
         number_section: yes
header-includes:
       - \usepackage{wallpaper}
       - \usepackage{\wpXoffset}{7.0cm}
       - \usepackage{\wpYoffset}{12.5cm}
       - \usepackage{longtable}
       - \usepackage{hyperref}        
---

some text
\newpage

# Introduction 

\newpage

# Mytables


```{r, tables,echo = FALSE, results= "asis"}

y= 1;
for (current_table in table$tablename)
{
  cat("##",current_schema);

   for (current_subtable in subtable$field_name)
      name_subtable = paste("###",subtable$field_name[y],"",sep = "");
      cat(name_subtable,"\n","&nbsp",fill = TRUE);
     y = y + 1
}
```
````

i.e. When I click on:

Introduction...........................................6

I would like to go at page 6.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Try adding `toc: yes` to your `pdf_document:` section of the header.  That should be all you need.

Comment: Hi @Benjamin, I have tried it however is not working for me. With toc = yes my contens has 2 layers instead of 3 i.e. 1 2 2.1 instead of 1 2 2.1 2.1.1 2.1.2 and Iinks are not working. I am using Foxit Reader to open the file.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 3):

Try below code.

```
---
title : "My report"
author: "Myself"
output:
  pdf_document: 
    fig_caption: yes
    number_section: yes
    toc: true
header-includes:
  - \hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue}
---
```